# Unable to add item to collection in Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this managed bean where I have a collection of addresses (each client may have N addresses) and I have a form using JSF (Primefaces) from where I send some data do fill an object (Endereco.java) and add this object to the collection.

After I send data I check the object added and it has all properties it should, the problem is after that when I check the first object in the collection list it is not there.

What could be wrong?

Action in the MB:

```
/**
 * Action to add the object endereco to the collection in this MB
 */
public void adicionarEndereco() {
    getRemetente().getEnderecos().add(endereco);

    limparEndereco();

    // At this point the collection is still the same it was before
    Collection<Endereco> addressList = getRemetente().getEnderecos();
    String logradouro = addressList.iterator().next().getLogradouro();
    System.out.println("String from the the property in the first item: " + logradouro); //

    // close dialog box
    if (true) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlgEndereco.hide()");
    }
}
```

xhtml code to send data to MB:

```xhtml
<h:form id="formEndereco">

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.logradouro']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.logradouro}"
                label="#{msg['label.endereco.logradouro']}" required="true" maxlength="14"
                id="campoLogradouro" styleClass="input-full-width">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoLogradouro" styleClass="error-msg" id="logradouroErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.numero']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.numero}" label="#{msg['label.endereco.numero']}"
                required="true" maxlength="7" id="campoNumero" styleClass="w80">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoNumero" styleClass="error-msg" id="numeroErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.complemento']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.complemento}"
                label="#{msg['label.endereco.complemento']}" required="true" maxlength="14"
                id="campoComplemento" styleClass="input-full-width">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoComplemento" styleClass="error-msg" id="complementoErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.bairro']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.bairro}" label="#{msg['label.endereco.bairro']}"
                required="true" maxlength="14" id="campoBairro" styleClass="input-full-width">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoBairro" styleClass="error-msg" id="bairroErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.cidade']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.cidade}" label="#{msg['label.endereco.cidade']}"
                required="true" maxlength="14" id="campoCidade" styleClass="input-full-width">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoCidade" styleClass="error-msg" id="cidadeErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.estado']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="campoEstado" value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.estado}" effect="fade"
                width="130">
                <f:selectItems value="#{estadoMB.lista}" var="estado" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoEstado" styleClass="error-msg" id="estadoErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box">
        <div class="colLabel">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.endereco.referencia']}" />
        </div>
        <div class="colField">
            <h:inputText value="#{remetenteMB.endereco.referencia}"
                label="#{msg['label.endereco.referencia']}" required="true" maxlength="80"
                id="campoReferencia" styleClass="input-full-width">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="colMessage">
            <h:message for="campoReferencia" styleClass="error-msg" id="referenciaErrorMessage" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_row_box" style="text-align: right;">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['label.adicionar']}" update=":formRemetente,formEndereco" id="btnAdicionar"
            ajax="true" actionListener="#{remetenteMB.adicionarEndereco}" icon="ui-icon-plus"
            styleClass="ui-priority-primary" style="margin-right: 5px;" />

        <p:commandButton id="btnCancelar" value="#{msg['label.cancelar']}" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
            onclick="PF('dlgEndereco').hide(); $('.ui-messages-close').click();" type="button" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the scope of the bean?

Comment: @RequestScoped public class RemetenteMB ...

Comment: Is addressList a field of RemetenteMB? Also, maybe try a session scope

Comment: Don't go with `SessionScope` unless it's explicitly session stuff. If it's for a view, use `@ViewScoped` as you're using jsf-2.

Comment: Still having the same problem, actually when I debug I see the item being added to the list but it doest not reflect on the bean values on jsf page. I need to update bean data end screen data where I have a dataTable with that collection.